# Trigger Concepts

Tags: trigger

Trigger is worked First time only if it updating the Record for second time it should be stopped ,because status have only one picklist value called activated, if you second time gets edited another New Record is Created, how to Avoid it

For this Trigger:

```
trigger createorderpricebook on Order (after update) {

    List<Order_Pricebook__c> orderPriceBookList = new List<Order_Pricebook__c>();
    for(Order ce:trigger.new) {

        if(ce.status =='Activated'){
            Order_Pricebook__c gh = new Order_Pricebook__c();
            gh.name= 'ela';
            gh.Order__c = ce.id;
            gh.Price_Book__c = ce.pricebook2Id;
            orderPriceBookList.add(gh);
        }
    }
    insert orderPriceBookList;
}
```

The Answer for this trigger:

```
trigger createorderpricebook on Order (after update) {

    List<Order_Pricebook__c> orderPriceBookList = new List<Order_Pricebook__c>();
    for(Order ce:trigger.new) {

        if(trigger.oldmap.get(ce.id).status!='Activated' && ce.status =='Activated'){
            Order_Pricebook__c gh = new Order_Pricebook__c();
            gh.name= 'ela';
            gh.Order__c = ce.id;
            gh.Price_Book__c = ce.pricebook2Id;
            orderPriceBookList.add(gh);
        }
    }
    insert orderPriceBookList;
}
```

The above code is working, but the order Must have only one Order Pricebook,if the Order gets activated, new record  is Created,but deactivate the order and again the order gets Activated,new Order Pricebook Record is Created, How to Overcome this Scenario

```
trigger createorderpricebook on Order (after update) {

    List<Order> orderList = new List<Order>();
    for(Order o : [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Order_Pricebooks__r) FROM Order WHERE Id IN :trigger.new]){
        // if there are no any child records, collect ids
        if(o.Order_Pricebooks__r.isEmpty()){
            orderList.add(o);
        }
    }

    List<Order_Pricebook__c> orderPriceBookList = new List<Order_Pricebook__c>();
    //  iterate over collected records and create child records
    for(Order ce:orderList) {

        if(ce.status =='Activated'){
            Order_Pricebook__c gh = new Order_Pricebook__c();
            gh.name= 'ela';
            gh.Order__c = ce.id;
            gh.Price_Book__c = ce.pricebook2Id;
            orderPriceBookList.add(gh);
        }
    }
    insert orderPriceBookList;
}
```

The above code first the order is Created, but while adding the Pricebook in Order it is Showing Error like

> Error: Invalid Data.  Review all error messages below to correct your
>   data. Cannot change pricebook at this time; error on Order: SObject
>   row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field:
>   Order.Status

**Anyone Guide Me how to Write a Trigger , for order must be activated ,it have a Create a New order Pricebook,second time it gets Deactivated to activated, No New order Pricebook have been Created,Share the Answer for Writting aTrigger**

**An order Must Have only one Order Pricebook**

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right. You just need to add the fields you use to the query:

```
 [SELECT Id, Status, Pricebook2Id, (SELECT Id FROM Order_Pricebooks__r) FROM Order WHERE Id IN :trigger.new]
```

Another option, so you don't need to add fields is to user the Trigger.Map or Trigger.New:

```
for(Order ce:orderList) {
    Order ceTemp = Trigger.newMap.get(ce.Id);
    if(ceTemp.status =='Activated'){
        Order_Pricebook__c gh = new Order_Pricebook__c();
        gh.name= 'ela';
        gh.Order__c = ceTemp.id;
        gh.Price_Book__c = ceTemp.pricebook2Id;
        orderPriceBookList.add(gh);
    }
}
```